# Convert VB.NET Group By expression to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, group-by

I have to convert the following expression from VB.NET to C#:

```
Dim z = From d In db.GPSdevice
    Where d.CompanyId = currentuser.CompanyId And d.Type = "Trailer"
    Order By d.ListOrder Descending
    Group d By Geofence = d.GeofenceLocation Into g = Group, Count()
    Order By Count Descending
```

I'm confused with Group By section...

Comment: Minor nitpick, `And` should be `AndAlso`. `And` is the bitwise-and operator, not the logical-and.

Comment: @JeffMercado with some LINQ providers, you have to use `And` or a separate `Where` query, since SQL doesn't have any notion of  short-circuiting

Comment: @JacobKrall, that's irrelevant, it's the wrong use of the operator for this context and has no real effect. _If_ it was relevant, it's the query provider's job to build the query as required by the data source.

Comment: If you compile your VB program, then use dotPeek or Reflector to decompile to to C# - what does it show as the code?

Comment: @JeffMercado This is actually wrong. And is *both* the logical union and bitwise operator. AndAlso is the *short-circuited* union operator. For AndAlso to work, the provider must implement it. While they probably already do, it is possible to get a provider that does not implement all operators. But in general both are safe, and if the provider supports short circuiting it is better to use AndAlso. If it doesn't support short-circuiting but implements the operator there will be no difference in the execution.

Comment: @DrunkenCodeMonkey: thanks for the clarification. I didn't think the way `And` was used varies so differently in VB compared to other C-family of languages. It's a logical expression and in other languages you are encouraged to use the logical operators. The short circuiting is just how one would naturally evaluate it. Personally it doesn't sit right with me on using `And` there, I would reserve it only for binary mathematical expressions.

Comment: C# is the same way, if you use the & operator, it is both a logical and bitwise operator. It is a logical operator for bools and a bitwise operator for integral types. && is the short-circuited logical operator. Most of the time you probably want to use &&, but sometimes & is warranted, for example if you want to ensure all branches of a conditional are evaluated, to increment a counter with the ++ operator for example. Evaluating (a == 1 && ++b >= 0) twice, with a==0 and a==1 you will end up with a==1 and b==1, using the & operator instead you get a==1 and b==2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A literal translation would be

```
var z = from d in db.GPSdevice
        where d.CompanyId == currentuser.CompanyId && d.Type == "Trailer"
        orderby d.ListOrder descending
        group d by d.GeofenceLocation into g
        orderby g.Count() descending
        select new { Geofence = g.Key, g = (from g2 in g select g2), Count = g.Count() };
```

but this doesn't result in the exact same types as the original VB query.

Here is a more (prematurely?) optimized version that does result in the same types:

```
var z2 = (from d in db.GPSdevice
         where d.CompanyId == currentuser.CompanyId && d.Type == "Trailer"
         group d by d.GeofenceLocation into g
         select new { Geofence = g.Key, g = (from g2 in g orderby g2.ListOrder descending select g2).ToArray(), Count = g.Count() }).OrderByDescending(g => g.Count);
```

Comment: I think your first query would be correct if just removed the "g = (from g2 in g select g2)" part.

Comment: I've tested the first query after removing the part I recommended removing, and it seems to reproduce the original VB behavior exactly.

Comment: Interesting - I needed to put that in according to LINQpad because in VB the query doesn't have a `Select` and the `Into g = Group` adds a `g` to the result that is an `Array` and not an `IGrouping`. The `g = (from g2 in g select g2)` creates an `IEnumerable` instead of an `Array`, but is otherwise comparable (going by LINQPad `Dump()` method).

Answer (score 1):

Should be pretty straight forward once you grasp the syntax. You would do something like

> group "records" by "records.property" into grouped_set

Then you would do a select to perform get your key (group by property) and associated count. Your linq statement should look something like this:

```
from d in db.GPSdevice
where d.CompanyId == currentuser.CompanyId && d.Type == "Trailer"
group d by d.GeofenceLocation into g 
select new { GeofenceLocation = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }
```

Comment: some sortings are definitely missing

Answer (score 1):

Utilize [anonymous types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) after your `GroupBy`, which will allow you to `OrderBy` group `g`'s `Count()`.

```
.Select(g => new { Group = g.Key.GeofenceLocation, Count = g.Count() })
```

---

Using LINQ fluent syntax:

```
var z = db.GPSdevice
          .Where(d => d.CompanyId == currentuser.CompanyId && d.Type == "Trailer")
          .OrderByDescending(d => d.ListOrder)
          .GroupBy(g => g.GeofenceLocation)
          .Select(g => new { Group = g.Key.GeofenceLocation, Count = g.Count() })
          .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count)
```

Note:

- `g.Key` refers to the `d` object
- `g.Count` refers to the anonymous type's `Count` and not LINQ's `Count()`.